# I need to solved this linear algebra equation with an unambiguous solution

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra, symplectic-linear-algebra

You know that
$$\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
    a & b & b \\
    b & c & -b\\
    c & d & a
  \end{array}\right]
*\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
   a \\
    1\\
    b
  \end{array}\right]=
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
   0 \\
    0\\
    0
  \end{array}\right]
$$
For which a, b, c, d have the system of equations
$$\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
    a & b & c \\
    b & c & d\\
    b & -b & a
  \end{array}\right]
*\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
   x \\
    y\\
    z
  \end{array}\right]=
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
   1 \\
    0\\
    d
  \end{array}\right]
$$
unambiguous solution?

Comment: Certainly when the matrix has det. nonzero

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be the first matrix. The second one is $A^T$.

Matrix $A$ has visibly a nonzero element in its kernel (whatever $a$ and $b$), therefore isn't invertible; as a consequence $\det(A)=0$ which gives $\det(A^T)=0$.

The second system of equations having a determinant equal to $0$ has never a unique solution (either 0 solutions or an infinity of solutions).